# focus() doesn't work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, internet-explorer-11

I have the following *HTML*:

```
<div id="blocked-layer-parent">
    <textarea id="paint-textarea" placeholder="Enter text" autofocus><%-sometext%></textarea>
    <div id="blocked-layer"></div>
</div>
```

In ***IE 11*** *autofocus* doesn't work. I tried to use *focus* function like this:

```
$("#paint-textarea").focus();
```

or this:

```
var textAreaElement = document.getElementById("paint-textarea");
setTimeout(function() {
    textAreaElement.focus();
}, 2100);
```

but *textarea* doesn't get focus in ***IE 11***. I looked different decisions (for example [jQuery focus() sometimes not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326993/jquery-focus-sometimes-not-working-in-ie8) and [focus doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie)) but noone doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

***P.S.*** *textarea*'s *placeholder* is transforming in text (*textelement*) in ***IE***. I find it so strange. In other module of application I have *input* with *placeholder* for searching. This *placeholder* works like placeholder (it disappears after char inputing). After some dialog showing *placeholder* transforms in text and searching stops working. Maybe the problem is related to this?

Comment: try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947590/unable-to-focus-an-input-using-javascript-in-ie11

Comment: @wybeen ty, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I tried pure html and js on [jsFiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/logSl.png), and it works. Maybe css cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in DOMContentLoaded Event (After Page Loaded)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("elementID").focus();
});
```