# textbox focus not working on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code moves the cursor from one textbox to next once it meets the maxlength criteria.
Following code works very well in Chrome. For the first textbox max length is 3 so cursor automatically moves to next textbox. But do not understand why in internet explorer it does not do so.
Please help, I am missing the important delivery date. Please note that 'mobNum' is the class of those textboxes

```
$('.mobNum').keypress(function(evt) {
    debugger;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    $("#msgMobileValidation").text("");
    $("#divClientValidMobile").hide();
    var idStr = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
    var idCnt = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    var nextIdCnt = parseInt(idCnt) + 1;
    nextIdCnt = nextIdCnt.toString();
    var nextControlId = "#" + idStr + "_" + nextIdCnt;
    var strLength = this.value.length + 1;
    var limit = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
    if (strLength == limit) {
        //$(nextControlId).focus();
        document.getElementById(nextControlId).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [focus doesn't work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600186/focus-doesnt-work-in-ie)   & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947590/unable-to-focus-an-input-using-javascript-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

For IE you need to implement focus using `setTimeout`, So replace the line:

```
document.getElementById(nextControlId).focus();
```

with this one:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(nextControlId).focus();},20);
```

Note that you can put any value instead of 20 (its time in miliseconds), but make sure it doesn't cause latency. so keep it small (5, 10, 15, 20...)